# extract array list to variable

Tags: linux, bash

based on user input, select array list: based on array list we choose, example JKT, I want to extract array index value to use as input for other command.

bellow is script:

```
read -p "Enter xGW need to be binding = JKT|SBY|xGW11_YGY|xGW12_YGY: " xGW

JKT=(saegw1.jkt.node 167.162.162.134 saegw1.jkt 167.162.162.137)
SBY=(saegw1.sby.node 167.162.179.128 saegw1.sby 167.162.179.131)
xGW11_YGY=(vsaegw11.ygy.node 167.162.191.59 vsaegw11.ygy 167.162.191.30)
xGW12_YGY=(vsaegw12.ygy.node 167.162.188.64 vsaegw12.ygy 167.162.188.88)

if [[ $xGW = "JKT" ]]
then
  echo ${JKT[@]}
  ${JKT[0]} = a
  ${JKT[1]} = b
  ${JKT[2]} = c
  ${JKT[3]} = d
echo $a

elif [[ $xGW = "SBY" ]]
then
  a = ${SBY[0]}
  b = ${SBY[1]}
  c = ${SBY[2]}
  d = ${SBY[3]}
elif [[ $xGW = "xGW11_YGY" ]]
then
  a = ${xGW11_YGY[0]}
  b = ${xGW11_YGY[1]}
  c = ${xGW11_YGY[2]}
  d = ${xGW11_YGY[3]}
else [[ $xGW = "xGW12_YGY" ]]
  a = ${xGW12_YGY[0]}
  b = ${xGW12_YGY[1]}
  c = ${xGW12_YGY[2]}
  d = ${xGW12_YGY[3]}
fi
```

when running Script, we have bellow error:

[root@cacti]# ./binding.sh
Enter xGW need to be binding = JKT|SBY|xGW11_YGY|xGW12_YGY: JKT saegw1.jkt.node 167.162.162.134 saegw1.jkt 167.162.162.137 ./binding.sh: line 21: saegw1.jkt.node: command not found ./binding.sh: line 22: 167.162.162.134: command not found ./binding.sh: line 23: saegw1.jkt: command not found ./binding.sh: line 24: 167.162.162.137: command not found

JKT

You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root [root@cacti]#

my goal is to get a value, b value, c value and d value, so I can use it for other command.

please help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you look at your own posting, you will hopefully notice that the code is formatted in a way that it is virtually unreadable. Please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)  so that it is displayed in fixed point, each statement in a different line.

Comment: first thing I notice: `else [[ $xGW = "xGW12_YGY" ]]`

Comment: What would the expected output be if the user enters 'JKT'?

Comment: @j_b  the output should be:  a = saegw1.jkt.node  b=167.162.162.134  c=saegw1.jkt d=167.162.162.137

Comment: Doesn't something catch your eye when you compare the first `if` `then` body to the others? Besides, you omitted ten lines before _line 21_.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code as highlighted by @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu and @Armali in the comments on your question. Your first `if` block is assigning the elements of the `$JKT` array with the values of 'a' 'b' 'c' and 'd' rather than the other way around as in your `elif` blocks.  Further, your `else` block has a test that does not function so the `else` block will function as a catchall for any input  that is not 'JKT' or 'SBY' or 'xGW11_YGY'.   I refactored your code a bit to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "Enter xGW need to be binding = JKT|SBY|xGW11_YGY|xGW12_YGY: " xGW

declare -a target_array
if [[ "$xGW" == "JKT" ]] ; then
    target_array=(saegw1.jkt.node 167.162.162.134 saegw1.jkt 167.162.162.137)
elif [[ "$xGW" == "SBY" ]] ; then
    target_array=(saegw1.sby.node 167.162.179.128 saegw1.sby 167.162.179.131)
elif [[ "$xGW" == "xGW11_YGY" ]] ; then
    target_array=(vsaegw11.ygy.node 167.162.191.59 vsaegw11.ygy 167.162.191.30)
elif [[ "$xGW" == "xGW12_YGY" ]] ; then
    target_array=(vsaegw12.ygy.node 167.162.188.64 vsaegw12.ygy 167.162.188.88)
else 
    printf "Unknown option '%s', please try again\n" "$xGW"
    exit 1
fi

a="${target_array[0]}"
b="${target_array[1]}"
c="${target_array[2]}"
d="${target_array[3]}"
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d"
```

Pasting your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and implementing the recommended changes can be helpful as a first step in debugging your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The `-n` flag from the builtin `declare` if it is available, should be able to do what you wanted.

---

Here is how I would do/write it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Define the arrays
JKT=(saegw1.jkt.node 167.162.162.134 saegw1.jkt 167.162.162.137)
SBY=(saegw1.sby.node 167.162.179.128 saegw1.sby 167.162.179.131)
xGW11_YGY=(vsaegw11.ygy.node 167.162.191.59 vsaegw11.ygy 167.162.191.30)
xGW12_YGY=(vsaegw12.ygy.node 167.162.188.64 vsaegw12.ygy 167.162.188.88)

read -rp "Enter xGW need to be binding = JKT|SBY|xGW11_YGY|xGW12_YGY: " xGW

##: If there is no input given. Print the error message.
##: Exit with a staus of 1.
if [[ -z $xGW ]]; then
  printf 'No input given!\n' >&2
  exit 1
elif [[ ! -v $xGW ]]; then  ##: see `help test' for the `-v'
  printf '[%s] is invalid!\n' "$xGW" >&2
  exit 1
fi

##: Exit the script if the `declare' failed see `help declare'
declare -n xGW || exit

printf \\n

##: Define the array keys after the test/validation with `-v'
##: Mind you `keys' is defined/set and a valid var name and input.
keys=({a..d})

##: Loop through the elements (key and value) and create a variable
##: Assignment using `-v' flag from `printf', see `help printf'.
for f in "${!xGW[@]}"; do
  printf -v "${keys[$f]}" '%s' "${xGW[$f]}"
done

##: Just for the human eye to see. Not something important/useful
##: in scripting. Do not process or parse these last lines! See `help printf`
printf '%s=(%s)\n\n' "${!xGW}" "${xGW[*]}"
printf 'a=%s\nb=%s\nc=%s\nd=%s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d"
```

---

Executing the script gives you:

```
Enter xGW need to be binding = JKT|SBY|xGW11_YGY|xGW12_YGY:
```

---

Not enter/input `JKT`

---

Output

```
JKT=(saegw1.jkt.node 167.162.162.134 saegw1.jkt 167.162.162.137)

a=saegw1.jkt.node
b=167.162.162.134
c=saegw1.jkt
d=167.162.162.137
```

---

With associative array, with the `-A` flag from `declare` just replace the `for loop` with.

```
for f in "${!xGW[@]}"; do
  declare -A input["${keys[$f]}"]="${xGW[$f]}"
done
```

---

The last two lines with:

```
printf '%s=(%s)\n\n' "${!xGW}" "${xGW[*]}"
printf 'a=%s\nb=%s\nc=%s\nd=%s\n' "${input[a]}" "${input[b]}" "${input[c]}" "${input[d]}"
```